# Copy and Paste VBA when a cell contains a certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA written, but I want it to copy if the cells in column contain the word new.  For example; I have New, New- delete, New-add, new-available and so on.  So I really want it to look for the word new no matter what's after and copy.  This is what I have so far but it's only grabbing whatever value I tell it to.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

a = Worksheets("Combined2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Combined2").Cells(i, 1).Value = "New delete" Then

Worksheets("Combined2").Rows(i).Copy
Worksheets("Running Data").Activate
b = Worksheets("Running Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Running Data").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Combined2").Activate
End If

Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: `If Worksheets("Combined2").Cells(i, 1).Value Like "New*" Then`

Comment: Tip: you don't need to activate or select sheets & cells when using VBA. Just perform the operations directly on the objects.